# How to access a property/variable using a String holding its name

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

If I had two variables in Objective C like this where one holds the name of the other as a string

```
NSInteger result = 4;
NSString * theName = @"result";
```

How would I best access the first variable using the string instead of a reference to the variable? For instance if I had a lot of variables and would generate the name of the one I need by code I'd need a way to get to the variable using that string.

Comment: Can we have some more context? You cannot get by with putting things into a NSDictionary, I suppose? And do you need this for properties or variables ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Though not directly answering your question, it's possible to access properties (or ivars) of an object by

```
[object setValue:@"value" forKey:theName]
```

Similarly, the getter is `[object valueForKey:theName]` (thanks kevboh!)

Comment: Similarly, the getter is `[object valueForKey:theName]`.

Comment: Problem is, he needs to get the object itself based on a string :)

Comment: @JeroenMoons Still, Objective-C code is usually written in the context of a class, and the variables are in fact ivars or properties, in which case my answer solves the problem.

Comment: In that case you could use it yes. Still a rather strange way of doing things :) btw, small syntax error in your code: [object setValue:@"value" forKey:@"theName"];

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible in objective-c. Variable names cannot be synthesised by name. The variable name itself doesn't mean anything when running your code, the compiler converts it into a memory address. The name is just a way for the programmer to make writing and reading code easier.

Depends on your exact situation but you probably should be using an NSArray or NSDictionary.

Comment: Not me, but possibly because you just say it's not possible, without substantiating your answer.

Comment: I gave some more explanation now, still strange though :)

Comment: Regarding your edited answer - so how come ivars and properties _can_ be accessed like this? maybe variables can also be accessed, somehow?

Comment: I don't know why it is like that, I only know it is. Local variables can't be retrieved based on a string containing its name. Your method works for instance vars but that doesn't make my general remark invalid.

Comment: I didn't downvote it but you know what I'll vote you back to 0.

Comment: Thanks C.O., question was 'can I do this?' and saying no wasn't an option apparently :)